# How do I find the correct replacement parts for kohler toilet tank?

Tags: toilet

I need to fix the tank of this kohler toilet -- It is slowly and constantly draining into the bowl (enough so that the city called about excessive water usage).  I'd like to replace the parts inside the tank, and was wondering if these were pretty standard parts, or how I would determine exactly which replacement parts I need.[image]

Comment: Does the water valve come on periodically for a few seconds and stop, or does the valve leak a little water constantly (you can hear it)?

Comment: This is in a rental property so I haven't actually seen it myself, waiting to hear back.  Out of curiosity, what difference does it make?

Comment: Post a picture with the complete model number, it's stamped on the inside back of the tank but your pic doesn't reveal it. Anyhoo, you should find a good plumbing shop in the vicinity of the rental, remove the parts and take them down there. if you want to buy them before hand then the model # is needed. P.S. it's a rental, replace **all** the parts while you are there and save yourself another call out.

Comment: The ballcock (fill valve) is manufactured by Fluidmaster for Kohler, but there are some special models. The flush lever and flush valve are special too. A good plumbing shop may have the stuff in stock.